# How to make applications open on specific workspaces on startup?

Tags: command-line, startup, workspaces

I want to open Terminal and System Monitor on the 2nd workspace on startup.

What terminal command do i need run?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the **Auto Move Windows** gnome-shell extension. It can be added from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/). *(This assumes a recent version of Ubuntu running gnome)*.

[image]